# I am having the wpdb Prepare error and I do not know how to modify it

Tags: wordpress, prepared-statement

I am trying to fix the wpdb :: prepare error called incorrectly. But after struggling for a while, I completely gave up.

Here is my code:

```
$numOne = 1;
$where = "WHERE id = %d";
$dataCallButton = "SELECT * FROM $wmtp_table_mobile_menu $where";
$get_data = $wpdb->get_results($wpdb->prepare( $dataCallButton, $numOne));
foreach ($get_data as $info) {
  $info->button_name;
  $info->button_link;
}
```

Someone please help me!
Thanks!

Comment: Have you defined the $wpdb variable in your function? ```global $wpdb;```

Comment: What is the exact error?

Comment: yes, I have defined the variable global $wpdb.  The following is the exact error: https://prnt.sc/saq6tu

Comment: I would try not using the variables in the prepare. Try this ```$get_data = $wpdb->get_results($wpdb->prepare( "SELECT * FROM $wmtp_table_mobile_menu WHERE id = %d", $numOne));```

Comment: Ok, but I have just tried this but have not fixed the above error!

Comment: The table name should be in the format ```$wpdb->term_taxonomy``` or just hardcode the exact table name if it is not a standard Wordpress table.

Comment: Look at the documentation for `prepare` you need to write the query like a `sprintf` : https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/classes/wpdb/prepare/

Comment: I have tried change to: https://prnt.sc/saqkus
But it still does not work

Comment: ```$wpdb->prefix``` is not a table!

Comment: Whatever the actual name of the table is you should hardcode it in the SQL.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a variable as the table name if it is in the format `$wpdb->term_taxonomy`. Assuming it is not a standard WordPress table you should hardcode it, or it looks like you can use `$wpdb->prefix` like this, if your prefix/table combination is "wmtp_mm", from [this comment](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/classes/wpdb/prepare/#comment-2331)...

```
global $wpdb;
$table_name = "{$wpdb->prefix}mm";
$numOne = 1;
$get_data = $wpdb->get_results($wpdb->prepare( "SELECT * FROM `$table_name` WHERE id = %d", $numOne));
foreach ($get_data as $info) {
  $info->button_name;
  $info->button_link;
}
```

Comment: I tried doing it. My table name is placed in the variable as follows $wmtp_table_mobile_menu = $wpdb-> prefix. 'wmtp_mm';

Comment: what is the table name?

Comment: The table name is wmtp_mm

Comment: I've updated the answer. This assumes your prefix in the wp-config.php file is "wmtp_".

Comment: Sorry, my board name is wp_wmtp_mm